# nextgen gallery: how to get picture url by gallery id

Tags: custom-field, plugin-nextgen-gallery

All posts in my site have custom field with nextgen gallery ID. To display gallery I use this code:

```
$gallery_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'galerijos_id', true); // Get gallery id from custom field data
 if( $gallery_id ){
   echo '<div class="post-gallery">';
   echo nggShowGallery( $gallery_id ); // Display the gallery
   echo '</div>';
```

How do I get pictures urls by gallery ID? I need url to pass to xml file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

After analyzing nextgen core files I have found solution to my problem. I hope it will be useful for somebody.

```
global $nggdb;

$get_gall_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'galerijos_id', true);
$gall_ids = $nggdb->get_ids_from_gallery($get_gall_id);
$images = $nggdb->get_gallery($get_gall_id);

foreach ( $gall_ids as $gall_id ) {
echo $images[$gall_id]->imageURL .'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me Paulius's answer wasn't working, here is the change that worked

```
global $nggdb;

$get_gall_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'galerijos_id', true);
$img_ids = $nggdb->get_ids_from_gallery($get_gall_id);

foreach ( $img_ids as $img_id ) {
 $img = $nggdb->find_image($img_id);
 echo $img->get_permalink() .'<br>';
}
```